# xslt to excel in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, xml, excel, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have to Export to excel from my asp.net page.I want to take the route of xml/xsl to excel instead of datagrid export.In the web I got how to do that.
[enter link description here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ar/csharpgeneral/thread/c7ec0b70-9330-4af1-b8ec-d60118d71cac)
I like to know how to format the xsl with column span,colours,row span etc..

```
<Table>
        <Row>
            <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Row 1, Col 1</Data></Cell>
            <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Row 1, Col 2</Data></Cell>
            <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Row 1, Col 3</Data></Cell>
            <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Row 1, Col 4</Data></Cell>
       </Row>
```

The xsl is like above I like to know how to do the formatting columnspan,giving colors etc...any document available.If i give plain xsl with html formatting when I load in excel it's not showing.

Comment: have you tried to format an Excel file manually and to look at its source code?

Comment: HI,Thanks for your reply can I know How to view the source code.from developer tab when I view code it goes to Macros editor.How to see the design.

Comment: `.xlxs` files are zip files that contain xml,, but i don't know about `.xls` - you can save the file in xml formatt i guess, if the tool does not support reading Excel files as well as writing them..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how much will this be helpful but try to save your excel sheet into xml spreadsheet 2007/2010 format. and then try to open it using notepad, you can see the source code. also that if you try to modify anything inside the notepad, you'll see the output in the excel sheet.