# XSLT Xml to Excel. PageBreaks handling

Tags: xml, excel, xslt

I have some data in XML and I have to export it to Excel xml.
I have pagebreaks in source XML file declared as simple tags : `<pageBreak/>`.
But in Excel-xml PageBreaks should be declared in worksheet as list of rowBreaks with numbers. Something like this:
It looks like this:

```
<xsl:template match="report">
<xsl:variable name="cols" select="./table[1]/cols"/>
<Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
  <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="26" ss:ExpandedRowCount="65535" x:FullColumns="1" x:FullRows="1" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
  ..........................
  </Table>

  <PageBreaks xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
    <RowBreaks>
     **?????????????
    </RowBreaks>
  </PageBreaks>
 </Worksheet>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="pageBreak" mode="report-root"> ??????????  </xsl:template>
```

The structure of input XML:

```
<root>
  <table>...</table>
  <blankline/>
  <pageBreak/>
  <table>...</table>
  <text>someText‌​</text>
</root>
```

How can I manage it?

Comment: I'd have to see a sample of your input XML format, but I strongly suspect you will be doing something along the lines of counting preceding-sibling nodes to see what row-number you are at for a particular pagebreak.

Comment: Not sure, how much it will help you, check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357262/xslt-to-excel-in-asp-net/10512235#10512235) !